# Is it possible to have integer array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `ToothSequence`  array which contains all integer type values

Whenever i want to compare the element or add integer i have to `parseInt` is as shown `parseInt(ToothSequence[i]) + 1`

```
 var ToothSequence = $("#hndBridge").val().split("|");
for (i = 1; i <= ToothSequence.length; i++) {
  if (parseInt(ToothSequence[i]) + 1 == parseInt(ToothSequence[i + 1]))
  {
```

Is it possible to make integer array in jquery? if not please suggest me

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291447/convert-string-into-array-of-integers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
var ToothSequence = $("#hndBridge").val().split("|").map(function(e) { return +e; });
```

`+e` will convert `e` to a number.

--for old browser which Array doesn't have map method, use `$.map` instead--

```
var ToothSequence = $.map($("#hndBridge").val().split("|"), function(e) { return +e; });
```

Comment: This. Maybe explain to him the +e though ;)

Comment: that looks sexy! could you explain the +e ?