# convert array of numbers that are strings into array of numbers

Tags: javascript

```
ids_nn
["50348", "18646", "17963", "18184", "30703", "18016", "23225"]
```

How do I make it:

```
[50348, 18646, 17963, 18184, 30703, 18016, 23225]
```

I read these two SO posts:

[How to convert all elements in an array to integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437916/to-convert-all-elements-in-an-array-to-integer-in-javascript)

[convert string into array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291447/convert-string-into-array-of-integers)

So, I tried:

```
var bla = ids_nn.map(function (x) { return parseInt(x, 10})
VM4765:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }message: "Unexpected token }"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: ErrorVM3550:847 InjectedScript._evaluateOnVM3550:780 InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrapVM3550:646 InjectedScript.evaluate
```

and

```
var bla = ids_nn.split(',').map(Number)
VM4648:2 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Your first try just has a missing `)` for the `parseInt` method. Other than that its just fine.

Comment: Doh! Thanks, accepting the answer shortly

Comment: What's unclear about "VM4765:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
var arrayOfNumbers = arrayOfStrings.map(Number);
```

- [MDN Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

For older browsers which do not support Array.map, you can use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
var arrayOfNumbers = _.map(arrayOfStrings, Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it into

```
var bla = ids_nn.map(function (x) { return parseInt(x, 10)})
VM4765:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }message: "Unexpected token }"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: ErrorVM3550:847 InjectedScript._evaluateOnVM3550:780 InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrapVM3550:646 InjectedScript.evaluate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var bla = ids_nn.map(function (x) { return parseInt(x, 10})
```

so close - here's what you should've done

```
var bla = ids_nn.map(function (x) { return parseInt(x, 10)})
```

one ) missing

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
var bla = ids_nn.map(function (x) { return parseInt(x) });
```

You had a mistake with the } and ), but anyway you don't need to pass the base

Comment: Thanks, am reading the documentation just now. Don;t get it, why don;t I need to specify decimal with 10?

Comment: If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:

In the parseInt documentation of w3schools I see:
If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is deprecated
If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal)
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: So you only had to specify base if your number starts with 0x prefix like "0x123A" which means you wanted it in hexadecimal