# Counting the number of events in a column of data, of a certain length

Tags: javascript

I am currently counting the number of `events` in my dataset (just a single column array of data from a .csv that I'm reading in), and counting the number of times that values change from 0 to 1.  If the value changes from 0 to 1, then I classify it as an event.  I also say that if the number of zeroes between two events is less than 60, then I classify them in the same event.

Now, I am trying to modify my code to only count events that last longer than 20 lines.  I tried to put it into my conditional like, `if(lines[i] != 0 && i>20)`, but I wasn't getting the correct value for `ev`.

```
processData: function(data) {
        // convert our data from the file into an array
        var lines = data.replace(/\n+$/, "").split("\n");
        var ev = 0; // the event counter (initialized to 0)
        for(var i = 0, count = 0; i < lines.length; i++) { // 'count' will be the counter of consecutive zeros
        if(lines[i] != 0) { // if we encounter a non-zero line
            if(count > 60) ev++; // if the count of the previous zeros is greater than 5, then increment ev (>5 mean that 5 zeros or less will be ignored)

                count = 1; // reset the count to 1 instead of 0 because the next while loop will skip one zero
            while(++i < lines.length && lines[i] != 0) // skip the non-zero values (unfortunetly this will skip the first (next) zero as well that's why we reset count to 1 to include this skipped 0)
             ;
         }
        else // if not (if this is a zero), then increment the count of consecutive zeros
        count++;
        }
        this.events = ev;
```

Comment: You want to get the count of event that have at least 20 entries in them?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Correct, yes.  So if the event contains less than 20 entries, then I don't want to count it as an event.

Comment: One thing I didn't ask you the last time: Could events have 0s as values? If there is less than 60 0s is that mean that those 0s are not a separator but an continuation of the event?

Comment: I assumed there can be none and posted my answer. If I'm wrong please let me know!

Comment: I'll try it soon and get back to you!  Thanks ibrahim!

Answer (score 1):

```
processData: function(data) {
        var lines = data.replace(/\n+$/, "").split("\n");
        var ev = 0;
        for(var i = 0, count = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if(lines[i] != 0) {
                var evcount = 1; // initialize evcount to use it to count non-zero values (the entries in an event) (1 so we won't skip the first)
                while(++i < lines.length && lines[i] != 0)
                    evcount++;  // increment every time a non-zero value is found

                if(count > 60 && evcount > 20) ev++; // if there is more than 60 0s and there is more than 20 entries in the event then increment the event counter

                count = 1; // initialize count
             }
             else // if not (if this is a zero), then increment the count of consecutive zeros
                 count++;
        }
        this.events = ev;
```