# How to remove double quotes from beginning and end of numbered value in a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have data as follow:

```
let str = "1,2,3,4"
```

and, I want to transform it into

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291447/convert-string-into-array-of-integers

Comment: JSON.parse("["+ x +"]"). Use backticks instead of ""

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` and `Number()`

```js
let str = "1,2,3,4";

const output = str.split(',').map(Number);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "1,2,3,4"
const nums = str.split(',').map( num => parseInt(num) );

console.log(nums)
```

You have to split by comma , then you can map through the array of strings and `parseInt()` them one by one

Answer (score 0):

actually what you can use is `split` + `map` in order to create an `array` with the values, because they would be strings, you can use `+` operator to cast it to a number.

like this:

```js
let str = "1,2,3,4"
let newArray = str.split(',').map(n=> +n);
console.log(newArray);
```